# How i migrate my old javascript google sign up button for new sdk

Tags: javascript, google-signin

I want to migrate my old google sign-up button for new identity sdk. I included the new button codes in my project but I don't know how to edit my old javascript codes. My button codes:

```
<div id="g_id_onload"
    data-client_id="key"
    data-context="use"
    data-ux_mode="popup"
    data-callback="onSignIn"
    data-auto_prompt="false">
</div>

<div class="g_id_signin"
    data-type="standard"
    data-shape="rectangular"
    data-theme="outline"
    data-text="signin_with"
    data-size="large"
    data-logo_alignment="left">
</div>
```

My old javascript codes:

```
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();

    $("#user").text(profile.getName());
    $("#email").text(profile.getEmail());
    $("#gPhoto").attr("src", profile.getImageUrl());
}
```

Comment: this will help to migrate to new https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/migration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

new google identity service will provide token after successful login as jwt (json web token), you can decode in javascript as follows ...

```
    function onSignIn(googleUser){
    //here onSignIn is your call back function name
    var token=googleUser.credential;
    var userinfo=JSON.parse(atob(token.split('.')[1]));
var i,e,n,p
    i=userinfo['sub']; //ID
    e=userinfo['email'];
    n=userinfo['name'];
    p=userinfo['picture'];
    alert(e);
    alert(i);
    alert(n);
    alert(p);
    }
```